# How can I open just ONE div instead all

Tags: jquery, html

How can I open just ONE div instead all, cause when I click on the div ALL the divs opens... But I just need the clicked one.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".more").click(function(){
         $(".more-open").toggle();
       });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close-button").click(function(){
        $(".more-open").toggle();
       });
});


And this script:
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box2">
<a href="#show"><div class="more">click</div></a>

<div class="more-open" style="display: none;">
  Test
 <a href="#close"><div class="close-button"><br></div></a>

</div>

</div>



<div id="box2">
<a href="#show"><div class="more">click</div></a>

<div class="more-open" style="display: none;">
  Test
 <a href="#close"><div class="close-button"><br></div></a>

</div>


</div>
```

Anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the related element to close/open.

In your case the `more` button should toggle the next sibling element of the clicked button's parent, same way in the case of close button you need to close the ancestor `more-open` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".more").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".more-open").toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close-button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".more-open").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="box2">
  <a href="#show">
    <div class="more">click</div>
  </a>

  <div class="more-open" style="display: none;">
    Test
    <a href="#close">
      <div class="close-button">
        <br>C
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>

</div>



<div id="box2">
  <a href="#show">
    <div class="more">click</div>
  </a>

  <div class="more-open" style="display: none;">
    Test
    <a href="#close">
      <div class="close-button">
        <br>C
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>


</div>
```